# PHP Easily embeddable web statistics engine

Tags: php, content-management-system, web, statistics, embeddable

I'm developing a content management system and i'd like to embed a web statistics engine ( views, visitors, unique visitors per date, and so on ) into my backend panel, showing reports inside my backend itself and not in the engine external backend.
Can you suggest me any stats engine that is easily embeddable inside a pre existing cms ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), using their [reporting API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataGettingStarted.html), perhaps.

Comment: Yes i'm going to use analytics api if i can't find anything else :)